# settings windows stay behind if already opened

Tags: gnome, settings

I have an issue with [gnome settings windows.](https://i1.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/settings-GNOME-3-26.jpeg?resize=800%2C538&ssl=1)

If settings are previously opened in background, and if I click on this, the windows will **not** come on foreground.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVg47.png]

But if I click on the button with wrench & screwdriver, it will show up.

Issue is with all settings shortcuts (under wifi, bluetooth, power, wired network...)

It's not really critical, but kind of annoying :-)